# No notification when mail get into folders other than inbox(Thunderbird 31 Mac)

Tags: thunderbird, macbook

I am using thunderbird(31.1.0) mail client in my mac book air(10.9). The problem I am facing with it is I don't get any notification when I get mails in custom folders. I dont find any solutions.

Answer (score 1):

not an answer, but to display the picture...

never used Thunderbird, but on Mail I just add 'Play Sound' to the end of the rule. Maybe Thunderbird has an equivalent command?

[image]